# how to write to JavaScript to focus on next input when i select bootstrap select search dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

i'am trying write JavaScript that focus on next input when i select and press enter. but iam able to focus on text input on pressing enter but not able to do same on select drop down.
is it possible or there any way to do it

```js
$(document).on('keypress', 'input,select', function(e) {
if (e.which == 13) {
e.preventDefault();
var $next = $('[tabIndex=' + (+this.tabIndex + 1) + ']');
console.log($next.length);
if (!$next.length) {
  $next = $('[tabIndex=1]');
}
$next.focus().click();
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<select tabIndex="1" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true"  >
  <option >Alabama</option>
  <option>Alaska </option>
  <option>Arizona </option>
  <option>Arkansas </option>
  <option>California </option>
  <option>Colorado </option>
  <option>Connecticut </option>
  <option>Delaware </option>
  <option>Florida </option>
  <option>Georgia </option>
  <option>Hawaii </option>
  <option>Idaho </option>
  <option>Illinois Indiana </option>
  <option>Iowa </option>
  <option>Kansas </option>
  <option>Kentucky </option>
  <option>Louisiana </option>
  <option>Maine </option>
  <option>Maryland </option>
  <option>Massachusetts </option>
  <option>Michigan </option>
  <option>Minnesota </option>
  <option>Mississippi </option>
  <option>Missouri </option>
  <option>Montana Nebraska </option>
  <option>Nevada </option>

  
</select>

<br><br>
<input type="text" name="myname" id="myname" tabIndex="2" />
<input type="text" name="myname1" id="myname1" tabIndex="3" />
```

Comment: any help apricated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the tabIndex on the select element, not the option

```
<select  tabIndex="1" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true"  >
```

```js
$(document).on('keypress', 'input,select', function(e) {
if (e.which == 13) {
e.preventDefault();
var $next = $('[tabIndex=' + (+this.tabIndex + 1) + ']');
console.log($next.length);
if (!$next.length) {
  $next = $('[tabIndex=1]');
}
$next.focus().click();
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<select  tabIndex="1" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true"  >
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Alaska </option>
  <option>Arizona </option>
  <option>Arkansas </option>
  <option>California </option>
  <option>Colorado </option>
  <option>Connecticut </option>
  <option>Delaware </option>
  <option>Florida </option>
  <option>Georgia </option>
  <option>Hawaii </option>
  <option>Idaho </option>
  <option>Illinois Indiana </option>
  <option>Iowa </option>
  <option>Kansas </option>
  <option>Kentucky </option>
  <option>Louisiana </option>
  <option>Maine </option>
  <option>Maryland </option>
  <option>Massachusetts </option>
  <option>Michigan </option>
  <option>Minnesota </option>
  <option>Mississippi </option>
  <option>Missouri </option>
  <option>Montana Nebraska </option>
  <option>Nevada </option>

  
</select>

<br><br>
<input type="text" name="myname" id="myname" tabIndex="2" />
<input type="text" name="myname1" id="myname1" tabIndex="3" />
```

Comment: tried it not working i want it move focus to next input i.e tabindex 2